# How exactly does std::distance calculate the return value? unclear problem with a selfmade set-iterator

Tags: c++

For an assignment in university I need to program my own `set` that works with extendible hashing. I wrote the code for insertion, erase and whatever it takes and it worked fine. At last I added an `iterator` as a nested class and with my own test-program it worked well. now as I tested it with a program of my university the `std::distance(InputIterator first, InputIterator last)` function delivers a value that's about half the actual size of my set, if I use `begin()` and `end()` as the iterators. When I regularly test my iterator it works perfectly all the time: reaches every element in the correct order and fulfills all the requirements of the requested `forwarditerator`.
So my question is how the `std::distance()` function works internally to maybe find the problem in my program.

I dont program for that long, only in second semester and new here. 
So please be gentle and let me know  if you need something more to work with:)
greetings

I've tried to overload the `operator-` as well in case the `std::distance` function just subtract the iterators but it doesn't work as well.

```
//sorry i had to take the code out, because my university doesnt allow it for //this assignment in case of upcoming duplicates
```

no error messages, the output is just a bit more than half the actual size.

Comment: It would be good if you could add a short `main` that uses `std::distance` and produces the incorrect result.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but `(*adsptr).ptr[idx]` can be written as `adsptr->ptr[idx]`.

Answer (score 1):

> How exactly does std::distance calculate the return value?

Depends on what operations the iterator supports. Random access iterators support subtraction, and `std::distance` will use that. For non-random access iterators, it'll compare the first iterator to the second and if they are not equal, then increment to next one and repeat until they do compare equal, while using a counter to keep track of iterations.

You can see exactly what operations of your iterator are used with a debugger.

Comment: How does `std::distance` determine if it's been passed random access iterators?

Comment: @MarkRansom It would probably use `std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::iterator_category` which would be `Iterator::iterator_category` for non-specialised iterator traits.

Comment: If you know that for sure instead of just "probably", it should be part of the answer. In fact it may be a critical reason why the code is not working.

Comment: @MarkRansom I haven't read through all of the standard library implementations, so I cannot know for sure. As far as the standard is concerned, the implementation could use any test that proves the iterator to be random access. I doubt there's anything more practical than `iterator_category` though.